# jQuery UI Sortable “Keep Together”?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list of elements that work fine with jQuery UI sortable, but now I want to be able to group some adjacent siblings together. Is there a direct way of doing that, similar to the way a rich-text document has a keep-together or keep-with-next attribute on paragraphs?

For example, if I have items 123456, what’s the best way to keep 2 & 3 together, so that a) If I drag either 2 or 3, then they move together and b) It's not possible to drop something *between* 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a wrapper  around the grouped elements with help from jQuery methods **replaceWith()** to remove the wrapper and **wrapAll()** to wrap the group. This requires some juggling if what you start with expects the individual elements to be direct children, but if you're referencing those elements by a class selector, it should go pretty easily.

I also wanted to be able to optionally lock the first and last items in place, and the solution there was to get a subset of the direct children and omit or include the first/last elements via **slice()**.

If there's enough interest from anyone other than me, I’ll post some example code fragments.